# Custom wordpress REST API to accept JSON formatted input

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm writing a wordpress REST API using the WP REST v2. Is there a way we can process the incoming **JSON** parameters (instead of query params) within the callback function, which we define in the register_rest_route function?

eg:

```
function wpplugin_register_routes() {
    register_rest_route( 'testapi/v1', 'users', array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'wpplugin_process_json_params',
    ) );
}

function wpplugin_process_json_params( WP_REST_Request $request ) {

    // Process the $request which should be a JSON string
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution for this. WP_REST_Request object contains the JSON parameters so can retrieve it using $request['parameter_name'] same as the GET / POST parameters.